# Invalid default value for 'Date'

Tags: mysql, date, default

I want to set date as default value for date in mysql (not timestamp), but the following error appear

```
ALTER TABLE `RMS`.`transactionentry` 
CHANGE `Date` `Date` DATE DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
```

**Error**

```
Invalid default value for 'Date'
```

**Same Case**

```
alter table `RMS`.`transactionentry` 
change `Date` `Date` date default 'CURRENT_DATE' NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
alter table `RMS`.`transactionentry`
change `Date` `Date` date default current_timestamp NOT NULL
```

### Updated:

I don't think you can achieve that with mysql `date`. You have to use `timestamp` or try this approach..

```
CREATE TRIGGER transactionentry_OnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON `RMS`.`transactionentry`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dateColumn = IFNULL(NEW.dateColumn, NOW());
```

Answer (score 9):

The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

[For Detail: Refer dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Answer (score 1):

remember it could be an issue with MYSQL version itself 5.6 allows timestamp with out a default value and doesn't requires to set them as null however 5.7 requires you to explicitly set the default if not then nul

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL site:

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function     or an expression. This
>   means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column
>   to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The
>   exception is that  you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default
>   for a TIMESTAMP column.

So:

```
alter table `RMS`.`transactionentry` 

change `Date` `Date` date default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

should work.  Your issue was you're making it a string by placing quotes around it.

Comment: I copied this the above statement from MySQL IDE, But according to your suggestion, I remove the quotes and its same error,means not working.

Comment: `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'Date'` . columne type is `DATE`, not `TIMESTAMP`, hence such default value will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column definition with:

```
ALTER TABLE transactionentry MODIFY COLUMN `Date` date null;
```

Allow null works for me.

Comment: OP doesn't want to set the column to NULL, he wants to have the current date as a default value.

Comment: Nick, Although true, for many other people with similar situation this is a viable solution

Answer (score 0):

```
change `Date` `Date` datetime default 'CURRENT_DATE' NOT NULL
```

Use DATETIME data type for the date column instead of DATE. This will include the timestamp information.