# Setting default value for DATE type column to current date without time part?

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-5.6

**NOTE: The question is about DATE type, not Datetime nor Timestamp**

How to alter column of date data type to use current date by default?
I saw a lot of examples for `datetime` (with time part), but not for date. I have tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `accounting` ALTER `accounting_date` 
  SET DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
ALTER TABLE `accounting` CHANGE `accounting_date` 
  `accounting_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

I also tried with `CURDATE()`, `NOW()`, `CURRENT_DATE()` ...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818423/set-now-as-default-value-for-datetime-datatype

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull The example is about TIMESTAMP (datetime) column. My question is about DATE column

Comment: so this one then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: This one is for DATETIME also. I need for DATE...

Comment: datetime == date surely. youll want it as a datetime object so you can manipulate it later?

Comment: datetime<>date. I know the difference in data types. I do not need Time part and I do not want to cast it every time when I would output the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you cannot set default value for 'date' data type in mysql. You need to change the type to timestamp or datetime.

You may have a look at this similar question.

[Invalid default value for 'Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573586/invalid-default-value-for-date)

**EDIT:**

In version 5.6.5, it is possible to set a default value on a datetime column, and even make a column that will update when the row is updated. The type definition:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `creation_time`     DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `modification_time` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Reference: http://optimize-this.blogspot.com/2012/04/datetime-default-now-finally-available.html

Comment: He literally said Date, not Datetime

Answer (score 9):

I use version 8.0.26, this is working:

```
datecolumn date DEFAULT (CURDATE())
```

It does not work, if you don't use the brackets!

Comment: wrapping up with bracket, did the work. Thanks!

Comment: It works well in Mysql too.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL 8.0+:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `creation_time`     DATE DEFAULT (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'))
)
```

Comment: why do you use formatting when saving? formatting is normally used when you output the value

Comment: well, NOW() also outputs a value. In that sense DATE_FORMAT() and NOW() and other value outputting functions are not much different. DATE type accepts a string in Y-m-d format or a DATE object; where as NOW() outputs DATETIME object and its string representation includes time. there are many other options to accomplish this, but in this case what we do is, we set default value of creation time to this moment's date part. Basically we strip the time part of the NOW() output and create a Y-m-d string and set it to creation_time.

Comment: I understand what does DATE_FORMAT functions do in general, however in your example it's just redundant and even more, it is hurting performance. You can leave just  NOW() without formatting and it will simply work with the same output.

Comment: Having NOW() was issuing errors to me, maybe I was making some other mistake that I wasn't aware of... It's been a while and I don'T remember what exactly was the issue. However, due to that experience, I had the above statement as a work around at that time. Nonetheless, you are right about the performance especially for high INSERT loads and yes, DATE_FORMAT() is redundant. Also, yes I tried couple minutes ago and having only NOW() also works.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this question [Invalid default value for 'create_date' timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field), this error may happen when MySQL is in `strict` mode (which is default behavior, I believe).

If you want to override it, just disable all these checks when creating your table:

```
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

The warning will be still generated, however it will allow to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work in sqlite:

```
"date" DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I used a value instead like this :

```
not null DEFAULT '1000-01-01' 
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The documentation is pretty clear on this:

This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns.