# How to set date data type default values EMPTY?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE pegawai (idpegawai char (6) not null default ' ',
namadepan varchar (20) default null,
namabelakang varchar (25) not null default ' ',
email varchar (25) not null default ' ',
telepon varchar (20) default null,
tglkontrak date not null default ' ');
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''not null')' at line 6

but I want results like this, can you help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6zNw.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the `date` data-type can have a default value of a single space? Maybe this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805705/how-to-set-default-value-of-date-not-datetime-timestamp-column-to-current-date

Comment: When I run this I get "Invalid default value for 'tglkontrak'".

Comment: Remove `DEFAULT ' '` for `tglkontrak` column. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267480/150107.

Comment: `' '` is not "empty", it has one space.  Nor is it `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you have mentioned whitespace as default value for `date` field `tglkontrak`. `Date` field can accept either `NULL` or a valid `date`

if you can have it as `null` then

```
CREATE TABLE pegawai (idpegawai char (6) not null default ' ',
namadepan varchar (20) default null,
namabelakang varchar (25) not null default ' ',
email varchar (25) not null default ' ',
telepon varchar (20) default null,
tglkontrak date);
```

else

```
CREATE TABLE pegawai (idpegawai char (6) not null default ' ',
namadepan varchar (20) default null,
namabelakang varchar (25) not null default ' ',
email varchar (25) not null default ' ',
telepon varchar (20) default null,
tglkontrak date not null);
```

Comment: *`tglkontrak date not null default '0000-00-00'`* This may contradict with NO_ZERO_DATE and/or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE server SQL mode setting(s). [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=71d47d574547f8897dacd55f2c0544e1).

Comment: That's correct. it will if strict SQL mode is enabled

Comment: but I want results like this, can you help me? https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6zNw.png

Comment: Your edition is not correct - strict mode does not interfere with the problem. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=39bb35cc9d2bfdf340a694a6e32d67dd).

Comment: instead of `tglkontrak date` use `tglkontrak date not null`